# Is there a better Equivalent of Goto over multiple subs in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, goto, control-flow

Goto cannot go to another procedure.

If a condition is true in the called procedure, then I need the calling procedure to skip to the end of the calling procedure.

The Problem:

```
 Sub Outer()
    Inner1()
    Inner2()
    Inner3()
  thisline:
  End Sub

  Sub Inner2()
      If condition is true
        goto thisline
      else dostuff
        end if
  End sub
```

My solution is to set a variable and then use that in combination with an if statement, but that also means I need to make the variable public.

Ok so here is the actual code:

Without any solution:

```
Sub btnRun_Click() Handles btnRun.Click
    ChooseSaveLocation()
    Case_DatatoGet(DatatoGet:=cmb_DatatoRetrieve.Text)

    WriteDatatoDestination(datachoice:=cmb_DatatoRetrieve.SelectedItem, 
                                 Destination:=cmb_Destination.SelectedItem)
    Debug.Print("---------------Finished with Run----------------")

End Sub

Sub Case_DatatoGet(DatatoGet)
    If DatatoGet = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please click on settings and choose data to retrieve")

    Else
        Select Case DatatoGet
            Case "Company Info"
                GetCompanyInfo(txt_APIUsername.Text, txt_APIPassword.Text)
            Case "Prices"
                GetPrices(txt_APIUsername.Text, txt_APIPassword.Text)
            Case "Balance Sheets"
                Debug.Print("Write a balance sheet sub")
            Case "Income Statements"
                Debug.Print("Write a Income Statement sub")
            Case "Statement of Cash Flows"
                Debug.Print("Write a Statement of Cash Flows sub")
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

With my Solution:

```
Public ContinueVar
...
Sub btnRun_Click() Handles btnRun.Click
    ContinueVar = True
    ChooseSaveLocation()
    Case_DatatoGet(DatatoGet:=cmb_DatatoRetrieve.Text)
    If ContinueVar = True Then
        WriteDatatoDestination(datachoice:=cmb_DatatoRetrieve.SelectedItem, 
                                 Destination:=cmb_Destination.SelectedItem)
        Debug.Print("---------------Finished with Run----------------")
    End If

End Sub

Sub Case_DatatoGet(DatatoGet)
    If DatatoGet = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please click on settings and choose data to retrieve")
        ContinueVar = False
    Else
        Select Case DatatoGet
            Case "Company Info"
                GetCompanyInfo(txt_APIUsername.Text, txt_APIPassword.Text)
            Case "Prices"
                GetPrices(txt_APIUsername.Text, txt_APIPassword.Text)
            Case "Balance Sheets"
                Debug.Print("Write a balance sheet sub")
            Case "Income Statements"
                Debug.Print("Write a Income Statement sub")
            Case "Statement of Cash Flows"
                Debug.Print("Write a Statement of Cash Flows sub")
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

This just seems like alot of extra code to solve a simple problem. 
**Is there a better way?**

Comment: If you're using goto, therey's *always* a better way.

Comment: @dwilliss *almost* always.  There are still rare cases where it's the clearest way to express the control flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the return value to tell the outer function to skip the other stuff?

```
Sub Outer()
    Inner1()
    If Inner2() = True Then
        Inner3()
    End If

End Sub

Function Inner2() As Boolean
    If condition Is True Then
        Return False
    Else
        dostuff()
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't return true be before the end if? Is it a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: You can, but this shouldn't make any difference in the logic.